# Get variable from window in React app from jQuery file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React. I also have one file that is written in jQuery. (someone wrote it, and can't re-write it now due to not having time).

In that jQuery file there's a variable `var test = 2` and after some time, it changes to `test = 5`. I need to react in my React component when that `test` value changes.

So I did this in jQuery file:

```
  window.testPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       res(test)
     }, 300)
  })
```

In my React component, I do this:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(0)

    (window as any).distancePromise.then((val:number) => {
        setTest(val);
    })
```

but `useState` somehow is broken now. It says:

> This expression is not callable.   Type '[number,
> Dispatch<SetStateAction>]' has no call signatures.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  window.distancePromise = () => new Promise((res, rej) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       res("a value for test")
     }, 300)
  })
```

Notice that I converted it to a function.

And use it like this:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    (window as any).distancePromise && (window as any).distancePromise().then((val:number) => {
        setTest(val);
    })
}, [])
```

notice the call-parenthesis `()`

EDIT:
I would recommend avoiding window variables in general. React has a lot of ways to avoid this, like context or  using Redux or any other state management tool

EDIT2:
Here is a working codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-visvesvaraya-36fmy?file=/src/App.js

EDIT3:
Never, i mean NEVER use jQuery with React..
jQuery is a DOM manipulator, exactly like React. But React is faster and better. Never use jQuery with React

Comment: 1. same problem, it didn't help. 2. how can I use context or redux ? the value is in Jquery's file

Comment: There is no such thing as a jQuery file.. it is simply a JS file. I added a codesandbox that proves it works.. 
On how to use Context or Redux I can't explain it with a comment or SO post.. You need to learn it yourself, there are hundreds of tutorials online.